# How to put boost::multi_array in initialization list of constructor?

Tags: c++, boost

I've got a templated class mostly dedicated to holding a `boost:: multi_array`. I am trying to initialize the array in the initialization class, but I am getting an error:

```
template <typename T>
class Hist2D
{
private:
  typedef boost::multi_array<T, 2> array_type;
  array_type MatrixCount;

public:
  Hist2D(int width, int height): array_type MatrixCount(boost::extents[width][height]){}; 
};
```

This gives the following error:

```
ctest.cpp: In constructor ‘Hist2D<T>::Hist2D(int, int)’:
ctest.cpp:34:45: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘MatrixCount’
   Hist2D(int width, int height): array_type MatrixCount(boost:extents[width][height]){}; 
                                             ^
ctest.cpp:34:45: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘MatrixCount’
```

What do these errors mean?

Comment: The error means you're trying to invent syntax of your own. If you replaced `array_type MatrixCount;` with `int MatrixCount;`, would this make sense? `Hist2D() : int MatrixCount(10) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a syntax error. You do not need to declare the type in the initialization list.

Try this:

```
Hist2D(int width, int height): MatrixCount(boost::extents[width][height]){}
```

C++ compilation errors can be confusing. You'll get used to them after a while :D

Comment: @Praetorian thanks for the fix up, didn't spot those mistakes

Comment: Yup, I always find that the toughest part of learning a new language, and C++ does seem more confounding than others. Thanks a lot.